# Increase area of convex hull by x percentage with lat / lon coordinates

Tags: python, scipy

I calculating a convex hull of some random coordinates with scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.

[image]

Now I want to increase the area by a given percentage. I have looked on scipy to find a method but I could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org). GeoPandas will give you more options for geospatial data then scipy.

You can plot the data for example with `plotly`. The image shows a result with a scale factor of 2.

[image]